# Is it possible to determine free surface velocity experimentally of the liquid rotating in a cylinder?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, kinematics, rotational-dynamics

Hello Physics StackExchange Team,

I want to know whether it is possible to experimentally determine the velocity at which the free liquid surface is moving/rotating in a cylinder with a rotating disk. The velocity at the free surface will be lower (in comparison to the disc speed) but is there any way to experimentally capture/calculate it?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Small particles floating on top plus a video camera.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. I tried doing this but the turbulency was quite higher so this failed.

Comment: Why the close votes? This is real physics, not a mere whiteboard story about it.

Comment: Sounds like you need a faster camera.

Comment: If there is significant turbulence than indeed life will be more difficult. The principle still applies but you might need to vary the size of the markers as @JohnDoty mentions. You also might start at relatively slow rotation velocities. Also, if you are generating vortices then you, of course, no longer have a nice velocity field to map in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response, Sir. I tried with the large-size particles but within a few seconds the particles went underneath and were not seen with the naked eye and neither in the recording. But from the side of the container it was seen rotating. So do we have an alternative to this?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to visualize the flow using floating particles. L. F. Richardson's [famous parsnips](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/abs/10.1098/rspa.2004.1433) might be a bit large for your purpose, but you should be able to find something suitable. Then, make a movie, and do some measurements of successive frames.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. In case the turbulency is high or for a baffled container, this might not work I guess?